# Stop PocketSphinx LiveSpeech in its thread

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

I am implementing a simple Python application that runs PocketSphinx recognition from microphone in its own worker thread, sending the recognition output via queue to the main thread that runs Tkinter GUI.
In the worker thread, there is a for loop reading from the LiveSpeech iterator class.

Now, when the Tkinter window is closed, I would like to terminate the worker thread as well. The issue is that it is blocked in the for loop (at the line `for phrase in self.__speech:` in `pocketsphinx_inmic.py`) and it only continues when there is any input from the microphone. I would like to find a mechanism that allows me to "unblock" and let me terminate the thread (i.e. without any input on microphone). Could anyone suggest how to could I do so?

I was trying some stupid things like trying to rewrite the PocketSphinx_InMic.__speech with a new iterator in hope that it will unblock the read, but with no luck. I can't find the implementation code for the LiveSpeech class, which makes it more difficult.
I would even accept a suggestion on how to kill the thread in some dirty way - it's just a demo, no production code...

The whole code is below.

pocketsphinx_inmic.py:

```py
from pocketsphinx import Pocketsphinx, get_model_path, LiveSpeech
import nonblock_queue

class PocketSphinx_InMic:
    """ Wrapper class for PocketSphinx live recognition from a microphone. Shall be used as backend for the
    GUI demo application. """

    def __init__(self, queue):
        model_path = get_model_path()
        self.__config = {
            # ...
        }

        self.__speech = LiveSpeech(**self.__config)
        self.__queue = queue

    def recog_loop(self):
        for phrase in self.__speech:
            msg = str(phrase)
            self.__queue.enqueue(msg)
```

nonblock_queue.py:

```py
import queue

class NonblockQueue:
    def __init__(self, size = None):
        if(size != None):
            self.__blck_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize = size)
        else:
            self.__blck_queue = queue.Queue()

    def enqueue(self, msg):
        self.__blck_queue.put(msg)

    def dequeue(self):
        ret = None
        try:
            ret = self.__blck_queue.get(False)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        
        return ret
```

... and the main code:

```py
from pocketsphinx_inmic import PocketSphinx_InMic
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from nonblock_queue import NonblockQueue
from time import sleep

def set_elem_grid(gui_elem, row_arg, col_arg):
    gui_elem.grid(row = row_arg, column = col_arg, padx = GRID_FRAME_PADX, pady = GRID_FRAME_PADY)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting the main program...")
    
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("640x480")
    
    out_text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width = SCROLL_TEXT_WIDTH, height = SCROLL_TEXT_HEIGHT)
    set_elem_grid(out_text, 0, 0)

    thr_queue = NonblockQueue()
    sphinx = PocketSphinx_InMic(thr_queue)

    sphinx_thread = threading.Thread(target = sphinx.recog_loop)
    sphinx_thread.start()

    while(1):
        try:
            msg = thr_queue.dequeue()
            if(msg):
                out_text.insert(index = tk.INSERT, chars = str(msg) + "\n")
            window.update_idletasks()
            window.update()
            sleep(0.1)
        except:
            # if the window is closed, exception is thrown - just quit now...
            # TODO: we shall kill the second thread gracefully!
            exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

After finding the implementation code of the `LiveSpeech` class I found that there is a `stop()` method. Nevertheless, it didn't do what I would expect.
I ended up replacing `threading` with `multiprocessing`, where there is a standard `terminate()` method for killing the process. It feels like an overkill, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

The pocketsphinx modules seem to be only half written.  stop method does nothing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).